# Is there any function or method for finding the answer

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

find total number of elements in between the numbers 0 t0 10, 10 to 20, 20 to 30 and so on in an array.
say the array [23,14,67,17,87]
so there are 0 numbers from 0 to 10, 2 numbers from 10 to 20, and so on.

Comment: well, what have you tried?

Comment: x - (x % 10) returns x rounded down to the nearest multiple of 10 ... from there you should be able to figure out how to write a function, that does what you want it to do

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crux of the logic:

```js
const data = [23,14,67,17,87];

console.log(
  data.reduce((results, entry) => {
    // We only are interested in the 10s unit; the 1s don't matter.
    // This discards the 1s unit, and homologates numbers of the same multiple
    // of 10, e.g.
    // 14 → 1
    // 17 → 1
    const factor = Math.floor(entry / 10);
    // Create a human readable key, i.e 10 to 20
    const key = `${factor * 10} to ${(factor * 10) + 10}`
    return {
      ...results,
      // If the group has not already been added to the results,
      // this will set the value to 1, otherwise increment by 1.
      [key]: (results[key] ?? 0) + 1,
    };
  }, {})
);
```

You can always sort the groups if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. how the code inside the return statement works, could you please explain it.

Comment: For `...results`, this uses the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to pass back the set of results. `[key]` is used to dynamically set an object member, this will override anything from `...results` spread since it appears after. `results[key] ?? 0` uses the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to get the value of `results[key]` if it exists or otherwise use `0`. We then increment this by 1.

Comment: How can we output the result to zero for all the numbers that are not in between 0 to 10 , 30 to 40 , and so on. Since there is not any number between 0 to 10 so output would be zero and there are 2 numbers between 10 to 20, so output would be 2 and so on. Final output would be: [ 0 to 10: 0, 10 to 20: 2, 20 to 30: 1, 30 to 40: 0, 40 to 50 : 0, 50 to 60: 0, 60 to 70: 1, 70 to 80 : 0, 80 to 90 : 1, 90 to 100: 0]